# angular directive scope not binding data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a question, code like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="overflow-hidden ag-center" world-data info="target"></div>
```

js:

```
.directive('worldData', ['$interval', function($interval) {
    return {
        scope: {
            chart: '=info'
        },

        template: '<div>{{chart.aaa}}</div>',

        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.target = {'aaa': 'aaa'};

            aaa = $scope.chart;
        }
    }
}])
```

The chart value is undefined, and template no value, but when I declare $scope.target within controller, the code works, why?

Comment: With how your code works, I'd expect there to be a `target` value on the parent scope of the directive. The link function isn't doing anything that should affect the rendered values, as far as I can see.

Comment: When I use this, `link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

   $scope.target = {'aaa': 'aaa'};

   $scope.chart = $scope.target;
  }`   DOM render immediately. And the code works perfectly

Comment: Well sure, because you're redefining chart inside the directive. `chart: '=info'` is for passing in data from outside the directive. In this case you're passing `target` (should be defined outside the directive, presumable in a controller) to the directive via `info` which maps to the directive's `$scope.chart`. Are you defining target as the appropriate data outside the directive to be passed in?

Comment: no, $scope.target define outside directive works, and when I define inside link function, it is not work, it confuse me. And the angular document isn't say anything.

Comment: See my answer. The isolate scope `scope:{chart: '=info'}` is specifically only for passing in a value from outside the directive to inside the directive, mapped via an attribute, in this case a value passed into `info=""` will be mapped to  `$scope.chart` inside your directive. If you want to define the value inside the directive, then do that, either in `link` or `controller`, and just have `scope:{}` in the directive definition.

Comment: I'd recommend the egghead.io videos on isolate scope if you're having trouble. These concepts are very core to using directive, and angular in general.

Comment: Thank you very much to answer this question. I will watch your video to know angular well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be generally the pattern:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.target = {'aaa': 'aaa'}; //In reality, you'd normally load this up via some other method, like $http.
})

.directive('worldData', [function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            chart: '=info'
        },

        template: '<div>{{chart.aaa}}</div>'
     }
}])
```

--

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="overflow-hidden ag-center" world-data info="target"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, the directive could be responsible for going and fetching the data, and not pass in anything to it. You'd only want to consider that if you don't need the data in multiple places.